# Access to the docker app from a virtual machine

Tags: apache, docker, virtualbox

I have a dockerized app (hosted by Apache) on my local machine. I would like to test the app on IE11 and Edge. So I installed a virtual box to run the app on IE and Edge on the virtual box Window10.

However, it looks like I cannot access to the app's on the browser. Anybody who know how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two main things to check.

1. Make sure that your container exports a port to its host (eg `docker run -p 80:8080 ...`). This assumes that your app is listening to port 8080. Change it as needed.
2. Add a network interface to your Virtual Box. If you're on a home wifi network for instance, just add a Network Interface for that network. That will allow your Virtual Box VM to be accessible from your wifi network.

Beside that, you'll really need to put more information like the command line instructions you use to start your app (or docker-compose file), the result of `ifconfig` from inside your host, etc.